# Comparing timestamps in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, accesstoken

As the access token is valid for 20 mins in SFMC, I want to reuse the access token.
Hence I tried to write the below code.

What I am doing currently

1. I have created a Data Extension called - **tokens_DE** and store the fields - accesstoken, startDate, endDate, BU
2. Then in code, before making any API call first I want to check  if expireDate > now() —> which means expired

But its not working. The code always gets into else statement —> not expired even though it is expired.

```
%%[
set @now= now(1)
set @nowPlus1Min   = DateAdd(@now, 1, "MI")
]%%


<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1");
  
  
                 var now = Variable.GetValue("@now");
                 var nowPlus1Min = Variable.GetValue("@nowPlus1Min");
                 var bu =“US”
                 var expireDate =  Platform.Function.Lookup("ent.tokens_DE","EndDate","BU",bu)
 
                 if(expireDate > now)
                 {
                    Write("expired.....");
                    //invoke the resusable getaccesstoken function..
                    //var jsonresp     = getAccessToken();
                    var accessToken  = jsonresp.access_token;
                    var restURL      = jsonresp.rest_instance_url;
                    //Write("accesstoken :"+accessToken+"");
                    //Write("REST URL :"+restURL+"");
                   var upsert = Platform.Function.UpsertDE("tokens_DE”, ["BU"], ["US"],["startDate","EndDate","accessToken"],[now,nowPlus1Min,accessToken]); 
                }
                else
                {
                    Write("not expired...")
                    var accessToken=Platform.Function.Lookup("tokens_DE","accessToken","BU",bu)
                    Write("acc>>"+accessToken)
                }
 
 <script>
```

Please can anyone help me figure out a way to fix this?
It looks the comparison is the issue. please can anyone tell me how to compare timestamp of 2 values in SSJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general comparison logic is correct, I would assume the problem hides in something else.
**Suggestions to troubleshoot:**

1. Make sure "tokens_DE" Data Extension has fields "startDate" and "endDate" as Date datatypes
2. Print out SSJS variables `now` and `expireDate` with `Write("now: " + now + "<br>" + "expireDate: " + expireDate);` to see if you are correctly picking values for further comparison
3. Use [`typeOf();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) function to make sure both values are dates to make a further valid comparison of both
4. Not sure whether this is a typo but `var bu =“US”` is an invalid format and it cannot use curly double-quotes for setting a value, thus set it as `var bu = "US"`

**Tips on top:**

- You do not need to use AMPscript to set a timestamp into a variable and then add one minute, you can do it in JS this way:

```js
var now = Now();
var nowPlus1Min = now.setTime(now + 1000 * 60); // 1k milliseconds = 1 second
```

- Lastly, better to use double-quotes in `runat="server"` part due to the already found [issues](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000pbKRQAY) with that.
- I do not see how you set up your token expiry date but in fact, it has [18 minutes validity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/access-token-s2s.html):

> Length of time in seconds that the token is valid: approximately 1080 seconds, or 18 minutes. The actual access token lifetime is 20 minutes, but the expires_in setting is 18 minutes because we recommend that you refresh your token two minutes before its lifetime ends.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and detailed answer. Your suggestions for troubleshooting helped and the problem was with "startDate" and "endDate" were not Date datatypes.